# unable to copy HTTP pallete into mule config after updating the connector--getting createDecorator error Anypoint studio

Tags: anypoint-studio

[getting above error message while copying http pallete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rxRN.png) 
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit.coverage.CoverageFigureDecorator.createDecorator(Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/util/MessageFlowEntityWrapper;)Lorg/mule/tooling/messageflow/figuredecorator/IFigureDecorator;

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by updating the munit related updates.

**Anypoint studio -> Help -> check Updates ->select the required connectors and munit related updates -> Proceed with the update .**